# Google Sheets - how to find matches between 2 columns? (e.g. cross-match 2 lists)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Google Sheet containing item SKUs in Column A and JPG filenames in Column B.
For example:

```
Column A       Column B
ModelA4        random_image.jpg
ModelZ8        ModelQ1.jpg
ModelB7        ModelZ5.jpg
ModelQ4        other_junk.jpg
ModelP9        ModelA4.jpg
ModelA3        some_junk.jpg
ModelA2        ModelB7.jpg
```

Problem: there are MANY other extraneous values in Column B.

How can I find ONLY the values that exist in Column A, within Column B? And ideally, list them in Column C, in the same row as the "source" query? What I'm looking for is a list of which products we DO have images for, and which we don't (blank lines).

In other words, what I need to have as the output:

```
Column A       Column B            Column C
ModelA4        random_image.jpg    ModelA4.jpg
ModelZ8        ModelQ1.jpg         {blank}
ModelB7        ModelZ5.jpg         ModelB7.jpg
ModelQ4        other_junk.jpg      {blank}
ModelP9        ModelA4.jpg         {blank}
ModelA3        some_junk.jpg       {blank}
ModelA2        ModelB7.jpg         {blank}
```

Added difficulty: the image filenames may not be an *exact* match to the values in Column A. Is it possible to search for only, let's say, the first 3-4-5 characters?

Any ideas (or suggestions on another method of accomplishing this) would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX($B$1:$B$7, 
        MATCH("*"&A1&"*",$B$1:$B$7,0)),
  "")
```

This uses wildcards to find the string in column A anywhere in every string in column B.
Not sure I understand your added difficulty, you could substitute `A1` for `LEFT(A1, 3)`.